# AWS Lambda Function for EC2 SSH Security Check

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

AWS Lambda Function `EC2_SSH_Security_Check` not giving correct value.

```py
import sys
import boto3
from boto3 import ec2
connection=boto3.client('ec2', region_name='sa-east-1')
sg=connection.describe_security_groups()

#listOfInstances=""
#messages="Following Instances have port 22 open"

def getTag(instanceId):
    reservations=connection.get_all_instances(filters={'instance_id':instanceId})
    for r in reservations:
        for i in r.instances:
            return i.tags['Name']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        print(sg)
        for securityGroup in sg:
            for rule in securityGroup.rules:
                global instanceId;
                if (rule.from_port=='22' and rule.to_port == '22') and '0.0.0.0/0' in str(rule.grants):
                    for instanceid in securityGroup.instances():
                        instanceId=str(instanceid)
                        listOfInstances += "Instance Name : " + getTag(instanceId.split(':')[1]) + "\t State:" + instanceid.state + "\t SecurityGroup:" +securityGroup.name + "\n"
        print(listOfInstances)
    except :
        print ("Some Error occurred")
```

Expectation is show the port 22 which is open for all, but not showing correct value

Comment: can you please elaborate more and format your code properly.

Comment: i want to identify AWS EC2 instance which has SSH Security group open for all. but above code not giving the expected output. Can't understand where is the error in code/logic

Comment: What do you mean by "not showing correct value"? Also, your code doesn't seem to be handling the situation where "All Ports" are open (not just port 22).

Comment: import boto3
protocol = "ssh"
port = "22"
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name="sa-east-1")
ec2=client.describe_instances()
def lambda_handler(event, context):

 response = client.describe_security_groups(
     Filters=[
         {
             'Name': 'ip-permission.from-port',
             'Values': ['22'],              
         },
         {
             'Name': 'ip-permission.to-port',
             'Values': ['22'],
         },
         {
             'Name': 'ip-permission.cidr',
             'Values': ['0.0.0.0/0'],
         },
     ],
    )
 return (response)